what are the chrome crash situations while running react application in production environment
I am developing a React/Node.js/Express.js/MySQL-based web application that tracks daily work operations for employees at work centers. This application is deployed on Samsung Galaxy A9 tablets, which are placed near die-cutting and UV machines in an industrial environment where heat levels can be high. The operators log in, select tasks (e.g., "Production Start," "Daily Maintenance," "Idle Times - Machine Breakdown"), and the application displays a Material UI (MUI) Dialog for task confirmation. Once confirmed, an ongoing operation dialog is shown, which includes a small animation (.gif) for better visualization. Operators work in 24-hour shifts and use the application continuously throughout their shift.
The problem I'm facing is that sometimes the necessary data does not display on the tablet when it should, although the props are being passed correctly between React components. The application seems to lag or fail to update in real-time. Given that the tablets are positioned near heat-producing machinery, I suspect this could be related to either performance bottlenecks in the React application or heat-related device throttling.
I am considering the following possibilities:
Thermal throttling due to the tablet's exposure to high heat could be causing slowdowns or performance degradation, particularly during extended usage.
The React app may be rendering too many stateful components, especially when showing/hiding multiple dialogs or handling animations (GIFs) inside the dialogs, leading to poor performance on the tablet.
Memory or performance limitations of the Samsung Galaxy A9 may be impacting the application’s ability to render complex dialogs and props after prolonged use.
no problem occurred image sample, consider red circled area before compare1: https://i.sstatic.net/JfjZSMb2.jpg
problem occurred image i have added dotted highlighted areas for compare images

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

thank you for replay, i have added more details in question area.
